# custom theme cannot be inherited when use productFlavors

Tags: android, user-interface, gradle

here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/custom-theme-canno-be-inherited/tree/custom-theme-is-not-found-when-use-productFlavors), here is [my screenshot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aObDvOlqeBo&feature=youtu.be)
in old code:

mylibrary/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="RoTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>
</resources>
```

app/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="RoTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

it work, but when change

mylibrary/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

to

```
productFlavors {
   dev {
       minSdkVersion 23
       targetSdkVersion 23
   }
}
```

and hit android studio "gradle sync", it raise

```
Error:(218, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'RoTheme'.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Try adding `applicationId "your_app_id"` inside.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna raise same error

Comment: Do not change the `defaultConfig` to `productFlavors`. Add `productFlavors` and leave `defaultConfig` as it is.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I try keep both, but raise same error

Comment: Try overriding application id and version both as in the example and link I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<style name="RoTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="RoTheme"
       parent="android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

android:style denotes that it is an inbuilt style for Android

Answer (score 0):

> The product flavors support the same properties as `defaultConfig` because  `defaultConfig` actually belongs to the `ProductFlavor` class but Creating product flavors is similar to creating build types.

See [build-variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) For more info,
So leave the `defaultConfig` as it is and add `productFlavors` but do not replace that, You should make it like:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {...}
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            applicationId "..."
            versionName "..."
        }
        full {
            applicationId "..."
            versionName "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean [this](https://gist.github.com/dbaf141029047d9206a821f3bf3e978d), it raise same error

Comment: @asullaherc I still didn't see any application id.

Comment: sorry, i have publish wrong full code, I have update it

Comment: [manifest.xml](https://github.com/roroco/custom-theme-canno-be-inherited/blob/custom-theme-is-not-found-when-use-productFlavors/app/build.gradle) has package name and [build.gradle](https://github.com/roroco/custom-theme-canno-be-inherited/blob/custom-theme-is-not-found-when-use-productFlavors/app/build.gradle) has application id

Comment: You still didn't refer the manifest.xml... See [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) as well to be clear of what I was telling .

Comment: i'm very sure [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/roroco/custom-theme-canno-be-inherited/blob/custom-theme-is-not-found-when-use-productFlavors/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) has package id and it's same with [build.gradle](https://github.com/roroco/custom-theme-canno-be-inherited/blob/custom-theme-is-not-found-when-use-productFlavors/app/build.gradle) applicationId

Comment: [your page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) has a little diff with my case, I use define productFlavors in mylibrary module

Comment: is `support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` also giving the problem ? really I could not identify you exact issue bro..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the bug only occurs in

```
compile project(path: ":mylibrary")
```

if I use following code will work:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'ro.mylibrary:mylibrary-dev-release:1.0@aar'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "$System.env.HOME/Dropbox/try/adr/product-flavor-make-custom-theme-inheritance-failed/mylibrary/build/outputs/aar"
    }
}
```

so if I use productFlavors in my library, the bug only occurs in dummy project, that's no big problem.